# Does SSHTunnelForwarder supports .ppk extension file as private key?

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh-tunnel

```
import psycopg2
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder



tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('ip', 22),
         ### in my case, I used a private key instead of a password
        ssh_username = "username",
        ssh_pkey = 'C:/Users/publickey.ppk',
        remote_bind_address = ('localhost', 5432),
        local_bind_address = ('localhost', 1234)) 

tunnel.start()
print("server connected")

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='dbname',
                                user='user',
                                host='host',
                                port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                password ='password', )

print("database connected")
```

> I got this code through a random search in internet.I have the private key file in the .ppk extension. When I run the above code I get the error saying **ValueError: No password or public key available!**.Is the error because the private key file is in the .ppk extension?.Does the sshTunnelforwarder supports .ppk extension?

Comment: `PPK` is used by **Putty** to combine the Public and Private keys. [Extract](https://superuser.com/a/232365) the private key and use it. Also make sure you connect through the tunnel (use `host="localhost"`)

Comment: Thank you. Let me try extracting the private key and use it.